# Extra space While adding Grid View to ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, gridview

I am using GridView which is inside scrollview(i know bad practice but requirements are like this only). The problem is their is unwanted extra vertical space coming at the end of GridView. I am also setting the height of GridView dynamically by this code.

```
 public static void setHeightDynamically(GridView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null)
            return;

        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int totalHeight = 0;
        View view = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
            view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
```

My xml is like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header_section"
        layout="@layout/header_screen" />


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/parent_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"

        android:layout_below="@+id/header_section">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frame"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp" />





            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                ></ListView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/more"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"

                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/icon"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txt"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txt"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/demo_demo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/items_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:numColumns="2" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>

<include layout="@layout/nav_drawer" />
```

Comment: Try to add your ScrollView content to GridView header.

Comment: can you add demo to show how this is done?

Comment: use android:fillViewPort = "true" in your scroll view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make increment according to the number of columns in your grid view , here i am assuming number of coulmns are 2 so just Make an increment of +2 in your loop

```
public static void setHeightDynamically(GridView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null)
            return;

        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int totalHeight = 0;
        View view = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i = i+2) {
            view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
            view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
```